# fetching index of an element in dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave

How to fetch an index of an element of an array in Dataweave.(mule)

Ex: Array --> ["a","b","c","d"]
    element --> c

```
Need to fetch the index of element "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
payload find "c"
```

That will return an array with all the indexes that match "c"